# How ifthen \equal could compare \relax to another \relax-like command?

Tags: bugs, ifthenelse

I was implementing an *ad hoc* list data structure inside LaTeX, where
`\aaa` expands value for aaa, `\bbb` exapnds value for bbb and to show that \bbb is next to \aaa on the list, `\NEXTaaa` expand to bbb, and I do not define `\NEXTbbb`. These definitions are done with `\@namedef`.

Using ifthen macros to work the code, I found a (supposedly) bug. I cannot compare `\relax` to macros `\relax`-like, like the one got after expansion of `\csname UndefinedCmd\endcsname`.

The question is: after `\let\abc\relax`, how to get a successfully compare `\abc` with `\relax` using ifthen macros? I am actually getting `\equal{\abc}{\relax}` -> false!!!  Is this a bug on `ifthen`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\let\abc\relax

\ifthenelse{\equal{\abc}{\relax}}
  {Good!}
  {Bad :-(}

%% I read Bad :-( on PDF file.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\equal` doesn't actually compare the _meaning_ of `\abc` and `\relax`.  It does `\def\a{\abc}`, `\def\b{\relax}`, then compares `\a` and `\b`, which contain different things, so are different.

Comment: Ok, but how to get \ifx-like comparison inside ifthen?

Comment: A work-around I used: define a boolean and before use \ifthenelse or \whiledo, I set the boolean with \ifx and use the boolean... but I loose ifthen practicality.

Comment: The hands-down best solution to do that with `ifthen` is to _not use_ `ifthen` :)

Comment: It would be very handy extend ifthen creating a \equalx{\csA}{\csB} that tests expansion of command sequences \csA and \csB, thai is, a version of \ifx comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably not use `ifthen`.  Maybe `etoolbox`'s `\ifboolexpr` or something more robust.  But if you must, here are two options.

1. Redefine `ifthen`'s `\isundefined` to consider `\relax` as undefined:

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{ifthen}

   \makeatletter
   \def\TE@undef#1#2{%
     \TE@throw
     \noexpand\ifnum1=%
       \noexpand\ifx\noexpand\@undefined\noexpand#11\noexpand\fi
       \noexpand\ifx\relax\noexpand#11\noexpand\fi\space#2}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \let\abc\relax

   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\abc}}
     {Good!}
     {Bad :-(}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Add a `\isdefequal` to do an `\ifx` comparison (the arguments *must* be two single tokens):

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \usepackage{ifthen}

   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\ifthenelse
     {\let\isundefined\TE@undef}
     {\let\isundefined\TE@undef
      \let\isdefequal\TE@isdefequal}
     {}{\FAILED}
   \long\def\TE@isdefequal#1#2#3{\TE@throw
     \noexpand\ifx\noexpand#1\noexpand#2#3}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \let\abc\relax

   \ifthenelse{\isdefequal{\abc}{\relax}}
     {Good!}
     {Bad :-(}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Second solution is perfect to my application.

Comment: @MiguelV.S.Frasson Proceed with caution ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Not a drop-in replacement of `\ifthenelse`, but more powerful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_empty_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \blanktest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean     \legacy_if_p:n
\cs_new:Npn \modetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {h}{\mode_if_horizontal_p:}
    {v}{\mode_if_vertical_p:}
    {m}{\mode_if_math_p:}
    {i}{\mode_if_inner_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \enginetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {luatex}{\sys_if_engine_luatex_p:}
    {pdftex}{\sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
    {ptex}{\sys_if_engine_ptex_p:}
    {uptex}{\sys_if_engine_uptex_p:}
    {xetex}{\sys_if_engine_xetex_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\let\abc\relax

\xifthenelse{\eqdeftest{\abc}{\relax}}{true}{false}

\xifthenelse{\eqdeftest{\abc}{\relax} && \numtest{0>1}}{true}{false}

\xifthenelse{\eqdeftest{\abc}{\relax} || \numtest{0>1}}{true}{false}

\xifthenelse{\enginetest{pdftex} || \enginetest{luatex}}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

You can use parentheses, `&&` for “and”, `||` for “or”, `!` for negation.

[image]