# LaTeX3 case inside \equal

Tags: pdftex, expl3, ifthenelse

I have a LaTeX document where I have defined a switch case command using LaTeX3 syntax. I am using the case inside the `\equal` condition of an `\ifthenelse` command. However, I keep getting the wrong result; seems to me that inside the `\equal`, the switch case cannot be expandend.

What I am doing wrong? In the MWE below I am expecting "*Function is A :)*" but got "*Function is B :(*":

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\caseswitch[2]{
  \str_case_e:nn{#1}{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \caseswitch{#1}{
    {A}{Aaa}
    {B}{Bbb}
  }
}

\begin{document}

% expected "Function is A :)" but got "Function is B :("
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycommand{A}}{Aaa}}{Function is A :)}{Function is B :(}

% another version - does not work too
%\caseswitch{\mycommand{A}}{{Aaa}{Function is A :)}{Bbb}{Function is B :(}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: as egreg just posted.you have spaces from end of line apart from that it is a bit  weird to  use `\ifthenelse` when, as you show, `expl3` provides far better control constructs. What is the use case here?

Comment: In that case would be special case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1 then. -- that having said, in order to debug this one, apart from "staring at the code" I suggest `\tl_show:x{\mycommand{A}}`, `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_analysis_show:n{x} \tl_analysis_show:x{\mycommand{A}}` which will print out the blank spaces.

Comment: (personally I have a local package for debugging which prints out token lists [like this in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIsSe.png) so that you'll be aware of both whether there are spaces in the code and the catcodes of the tokens in the token list, without being unnecessarily verbose like \tl_analysis_show:n which is frustrating to read)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting case of the *spurious space syndrome*: you're comparing `Aaa` with  `Aaa`  (with two spaces around the string).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\caseswitch[2]{
  \str_case_e:nn{#1}{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{% <--- HERE
  \caseswitch{#1}{
    {A}{Aaa}
    {B}{Bbb}
  }% <--- HERE
}

\begin{document}

% expected "Function is A :)" but got "Function is B :("
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycommand{A}}{Aaa}}{Function is A :)}{Function is B :(}

% another version - does not work too
\caseswitch{\mycommand{A}}{{Aaa}{Function is A :)}{Bbb}{Function is B :(}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd use the simpler

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \caseswitch \str_case_e:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and also the reimplementation of `\ifthenelse` I proposed [elsewhere on the site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638420/4427) (see the link for examples of use).

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% Expandable reimplementation of \ifthenelse
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_empty_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \blanktest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean     \legacy_if_p:n
\cs_new:Npn \modetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {h}{\mode_if_horizontal_p:}
    {v}{\mode_if_vertical_p:}
    {m}{\mode_if_math_p:}
    {i}{\mode_if_inner_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \enginetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {luatex}{\sys_if_engine_luatex_p:}
    {pdftex}{\sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
    {ptex}{\sys_if_engine_ptex_p:}
    {uptex}{\sys_if_engine_uptex_p:}
    {xetex}{\sys_if_engine_xetex_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }

% a utility command
\cs_set_eq:NN \caseswitch \str_case_e:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \caseswitch{#1}{
    {A}{Aaa}
    {B}{Bbb}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% expected "Function is A :)" but got "Function is B :("
\xifthenelse{\streqtest{\mycommand{A}}{Aaa}}{Function is A :)}{Function is B :(}

% another version - does not work too
\caseswitch{\mycommand{A}}{{Aaa}{Function is A :)}{Bbb}{Function is B :(}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The spaces! Of course, I should notice that. Thank you! It worked perfectly! Thank you also for the reimplementation of ifthenelse.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not in Expl3 you need to be aware  of spaces at end of line. Also you never really need `\ifthenelse` especially if you are already using `expl3` which has far better control constructs.

```
\documentclass{book}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \caseswitch \str_case_e:nn

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \caseswitch{#1}{
    {A}{Aaa}
    {B}{Bbb}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\caseswitch{\mycommand{A}}{{Aaa}{Function is A :)}{Bbb}{Function is B :(}}

\end{document}
```