How to define a command (or similar) that makes a conditional expression reusable?
I'm struggling with the correct use of conditional expressions with ifthenelse at the moment. I would like to define a command (or similar) that represents a certain conditional expression in order to use it in different locations of the document.
Lets say I have two booleans
\newboolean{bA}
\newboolean{bB}

And then I want to test the following condition in multiple locations
\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}

I tried to define a command for that
\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}}

but it didn't work as I expected. Instead, the engine reported Extra \or.
I tried different approaches like
\newboolean{bAny}
\setboolean{\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}}

which did not work and
\newboolean{bAny}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}}{
    \setboolean{bAny}{true}
}{
    \setboolean{bAny}{false}
}

which did work for me, but this solution is only suitable if the result of the expression does not change throughout the document. This is given in my case but it may not be in others.
I am wondering how I may define a command that makes the conditional expression reusable. I am certain that it should be possible but I don't know enough Tex and Latex to figure it out myself.
Here is a minimal working example
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{bA}
\newboolean{bB}

% This works
%\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA}}
% This does not
\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}}

\begin{document}
    \setboolean{bA}{true}
    \setboolean{bB}{false}
    
    \ifthenelse{\any}{%
        Hi
    }{%
        there
    }
    %
    \setboolean{bA}{false}
    %
    \ifthenelse{\any}{%
        how
    }{%
        are you?
    }
\end{document}


Chosen Solution
In the end I opted to use Marijn's solution because it is simple and I was able to fully understand it.
\newcommand{\ifAny}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{bA} \OR \boolean{bB}}{%
        #1%
    }{}%
}

egreg's solution is elaborated and works as I originally asked for. It allows to write
\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA} || \boolean{bB}}

and to use it as a single condition or as a part of more complex conditional expressions. It is however much more complicated and may confuse my future self.

With \OR it also won't work; part of the problem is an expansion issue.

Alternatively, put the \ifthenelse in the command definition:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{bA}
\newboolean{bB}

\newcommand{\ifthenany}[2]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{bA} \or \boolean{bB}}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \setboolean{bA}{true}
    \setboolean{bB}{false}
    
    \ifthenany{%
        Hi
    }{%
        there
    }
    %
    \setboolean{bA}{false}
    %
    \ifthenany{%
        how
    }{%
        are you?
    }
\end{document}


+1 definitely the better solution

That is a good solution to my specific problem.
What should I do if I wanted to use said expression as a subexpression say \any \or \boolean{bC}? Could you elaborate on that if you knew a more general solution?

In this case I would say that you may want to use something other than the ifthen package. That package is really not built with something like this in mind.

@WillieWong egregs answer ist perfect in that sense. It is a general solution to all applications that I had in mind.

@Simon: my comment was made before egreg's answer, and was merely an evaluation of Marijn's versus my answer.

You can use a different “ifthenelse“, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665600/4427
The \xifthenelse command is fully expandable and covers more cases than \ifthenelse.
Logical or is ||; logical and is &&; you can also negate a condition by preceding it with !.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% like in ifthen.sty
\NewDocumentCommand{\newboolean}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:cc {@ifdefinable} {if#1}
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \newif {if#1}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setboolean}{mm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF {if#1}
   {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \str_lowercase:n {#2} }
     {
      {true} { \use:c { #1true }  }
      {false}{ \use:c { #1false } }
     }
     {
      \msg_error:nnn { ifthen } {truefalse } { #2 }
     }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { ifthen } { undefined } { #1 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { ifthen } { truefalse }
 {Illegal~truth~value~'#1'~in~\token_to_str:N \setboolean}
 {You~can~only~use~'true'~or~'false'~in~\token_to_str:N \setboolean}
\msg_new:nnnn { ifthen } { undefined }
 {Undefined~boolean~'#1'}
 {The~boolean~'#1'~is~undefined;~do~\token_to_str:N \setboolean{#1}}

%%% Expandable reimplementation of \ifthenelse
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_empty_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \blanktest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean     \legacy_if_p:n
\cs_new:Npn \modetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {h}{\mode_if_horizontal_p:}
    {v}{\mode_if_vertical_p:}
    {m}{\mode_if_math_p:}
    {i}{\mode_if_inner_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \enginetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {luatex}{\sys_if_engine_luatex_p:}
    {pdftex}{\sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
    {ptex}{\sys_if_engine_ptex_p:}
    {uptex}{\sys_if_engine_uptex_p:}
    {xetex}{\sys_if_engine_xetex_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newboolean{bA}
\newboolean{bB}

\newcommand{\any}[2]{\boolean{#1}||\boolean{#2}}

\begin{document}

\setboolean{bA}{true}
\setboolean{bB}{FALSE}% upper- or lowercase is allowed

\xifthenelse{\boolean{bA} || \boolean{bB}}{%
  Hi
}{%
  there
}

\xifthenelse{!\boolean{bA} && \boolean{bB}}{%
  Hi
}{%
  there
}

\setboolean{bA}{false}

\xifthenelse{\any{bA}{bB}}{%
   how
}{%
  are you?
}

\end{document}


One day I might make a package out of this.

Sorry, but I don't understand anything of your anwer. The most I can say is that it works perfectly fine. This is exactly what I wanted. The definition \newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA} || \boolean{bB}} works as expected now. To me, this proves once again that Latex, in all of its colours, is not very accesible to an infrequent non-power user. In this case I go with the answer by Marijn because I am able to understand it. Maybe your anwer will be helpful for someone with more experience though, so thanks none the less.

@Simon You don't need to understand the code; in the linked answer there are other examples of usage.

You are right. I usually aspire to understand what I use, but of course I am using packages without understanding their inner workings and I usually don't have to.
Can you refer us to a good starting point where to learn to do such tricks with the modern latex variants?

Note that the following works
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{bA}
\newboolean{bB}

% This works
%\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA}}
% This does not
\newcommand{\any}{\boolean{bA} \OR \boolean{bB}}

\begin{document}
    \setboolean{bA}{true}
    \setboolean{bB}{false}
    
    \expandafter\ifthenelse\expandafter{\any}{%
        Hi
    }{%
        there
    }
    %
    \setboolean{bA}{false}
    %
    \expandafter\ifthenelse\expandafter{\any}{%
        how
    }{%
        are you?
    }
\end{document}


Looks like my question wasn't too easy then. I prefer Marijns solution in this case, but thank you very much for you time anyhow.

Yes, I too prefer that solution. :-)
