Package jsonparse not working with \ifthenelse
I am trying to use the package jsonparse1 (github page here, with documentation).
I am reading some data from json files, and I have to fill my documents depending on the json entries, therefore I (try to) use the \ifthenelse control: problem is that it seems that the result of such control is always false. Reading the documentation was not very helpful to me, the sole thing I understood was that each json entry is stored in a string, even if it is a number.
How can I make this package work? Down below a MWE showing the problem. I compile my tex files with LuaLaTex, but this problem arises also with pdflatex too.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jsonparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

% Create a json file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.json}
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "Paris"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\JSONParseFromFile{\jsonFile}{data.json}

\begin{document}
    % Everything is fine
    The name is: \JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{name}.
    
    % In this case, I expect to have "the French capitol" 
    % but I get the string "Paris"
    The city is \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{Paris}}%
    {the French capitol}% 
    {\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{city}}.
    
    % Same problem with numers (the package stores 
    % entries in strings, for what I understood)
    The age is \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{age}}{30}}%
    {thirty}% 
    {\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{age}}.
\end{document}


1 I could write some Python code (or in similar language), but I would prefer to keep it in TeX.

Also see this discussion: https://github.com/jasperhabicht/jsonparse/discussions/31

From the package manual, page 4:

With the suggested change, but also with a better management of conditionals (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665600/4427)
% Create a json file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.json}
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "Paris"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jsonparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% Expandable reimplementation of \ifthenelse
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_empty_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \blanktest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean     \legacy_if_p:n
\cs_new:Npn \modetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {h}{\mode_if_horizontal_p:}
    {v}{\mode_if_vertical_p:}
    {m}{\mode_if_math_p:}
    {i}{\mode_if_inner_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \enginetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {luatex}{\sys_if_engine_luatex_p:}
    {pdftex}{\sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
    {ptex}{\sys_if_engine_ptex_p:}
    {uptex}{\sys_if_engine_uptex_p:}
    {xetex}{\sys_if_engine_xetex_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }

% a utility command
\cs_set_eq:NN \caseswitch \str_case_e:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\JSONParseFromFile{\jsonFile}{\jobname.json}

\begin{document}

% Everything is fine
The name is: \JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{name}.

% In this case, I expect to have "the French capital" 
% but I get the string "Rome"
The city is \xifthenelse{\streqtest{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{Paris}}%
{the French capital}% 
{\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{city}}.

% Same problem with numbers (the package stores 
% entries in strings, for what I understood)
The age is \xifthenelse{\streqtest{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{age}}{30}}%
{thirty}% 
{\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{age}}.

\end{document}


There is no capitol in France, but there's a capital city, namely Paris. 

And I read at least 3 times the documentation... Thanks so much! But when I correct the command regarding the city ( :-) ), writing \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{Paris}} I do not get the correct output.

@Eddymage Well, that's an \ifthenelse problem…

No, I mean if I put the correct field in checking the JSON entry: \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{Paris}}{the French capital}{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}. correcting in the condition name into city.

@Eddymage That's very curious. I introduced a replacement for \ifthenelse.

Wow. Simply, wow. Thanks!

@Eddymage You need to use \JSONParseExpandableValue instead of \JSONParseValue, but you also need to take note that the result of \JSONParseExpandableValue will always be a string (with category code 12). If you compare this with Paris (with category code 11), this won't match. But you can do \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{\detokenize{Paris}}}{...}{...}. (I added this important notice in a very recent version of the manual only, sorry ...)

@JasperHabicht Thanks, I actually tried with detokenize, but both on Paris and on the output of \JSONParseExpandableValue and it did not work, maybe because I had to use it only on "Paris".

@Eddymage It should not make a difference when using it with numbers … Well, I am happy you got it working!

Being the package author, let me add this very short explanation to egreg's nice answer.
First, as already was mentioned, you need to use \JSONParseExpandableValue instead of \JSONParseValue, because the latter is not expandable.
Second, \JSONParseExpandableValue will always contain a string token list with category code 12 (this is due to the way how the JSON data is parsed). If you compare this with a token list with default category codes (which means category code 11 for letters), this will not match. You need to compare with another string token list which you can easily obtain using \detokenize. Note that this is not necessary for numbers which have category code 12 per default in TeX.
Thus, the following will work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jsonparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

% Create a json file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.json}
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "Paris"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\JSONParseFromFile{\jsonFile}{data.json}

\begin{document}
    % Everything is fine
    The name is: \JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{name}.
    
    % In this case, I expect to have "the French capitol" 
    % but I get the string "Paris"
    The city is \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{city}}{\detokenize{Paris}}}%
    {the French capital}% 
    {\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{city}}.
    
    % Same problem with numers (the package stores 
    % entries in strings, for what I understood)
    The age is \ifthenelse{\equal{\JSONParseExpandableValue{\jsonFile}{age}}{30}}%
    {thirty}% 
    {\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{age}}.
\end{document}


As from version 0.9.10, I added a new command \JSONParseSetRescanValue with which you can do a category code rescan and store the result in a variable which you then can use in cases such as yours:
\JSONParseSetRescanValue{\mycity}{\jsonFile}{city}
The city is \ifthenelse{\equal{\mycity}{Paris}}%
{the French capital}% 
{\JSONParseValue{\jsonFile}{city}}.

I admit that I only in one of the recent versions of the pacakge clarified in the manual how all the parsing works exactly and why and where it is important to take care of category codes. Sorry for that, the package is still work in progess ...

Thanks for your contribution! I find your package quite good, it lets to use json files directly with LaTex without using Python or similar languages!

@Eddymage Thank you! LuaLaTeX has a built-in JSON parser (via Lua) though which also could be of use.

Yes, I wrote the code using your package and I was compiling with pdflatex, then I had to modify a couple of fonts, hence I moved to Lualatex. At that point I've been lazy and I did not want to modify all the code..
