# LuaTeX's \textdir primitive fails a string-comparison test

Tags: luatex, conditionals, right-to-left, registers

**A demonstration of the problem by way of a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\the\textdir =%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\the\textdir}{TLT}}{TLT}{TRT}
\end{document}
```

The code prints out the content of the LuaTeX primitive `\textdir` register, an equality symbol, and then the string `TLT` if the contents of said register is `TLT`, and `TRT` otherwise.

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

As a consequence the file `~/Test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer, it showed "TLT=TRT".

---

**Questions**

1. If `\the\textdir` expands to the string "TLT", why, then, does the conditional evaluate to the *else* case "TRT"?
2. How can I query the value of the `\textdir` register?

Comment: same as `\jobname` and `\string` it returns catcode 12 characters not catcode 11

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So how can I test the value of this register?

Comment: Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638420/4427 for a different strategy, where `\xifthenelse{\streqtest{\the\textdir}{TLT}}{True}{False}` will work (and, as a bonus, is fully expandable).

Comment: @egreg Actually, in my real-life code (as opposed to the minimal working example listed above) `\xifthenelse` causes a compilation failure, whereas `\ifthenelse` works smoothely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same as `\jobname` and `\string`, it returns catcode 12 characters not catcode 11

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\the\textdir =%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\the\textdir}{\detokenize{TLT}}}{TLT}{TRT}
\end{document}
```